# How to fetch data from mysql table and insert into another table using php?

Tags: mysql

Here is my sql query below

```
select Client, count(*) as Sales FROM sale_tbl GROUP BY Client
```

The query will fetch records like this

```
Client Sales
John     5
Bob      4
Doe      5
```

Now i want to insert this record into another table in the same database named data_tbl with three(3) columns of: `id(Auto increment), Client, Sales`

Comment: why did you tag this with laravel AND codeigniter?

Comment: please don't tag spam

Comment: You adding anything here?

Answer (score 3):

You can just `INSERT INTO other_table (Client, Sales) SELECT ...` with the `SELECT` you have here on the end.

That being said, what you want is probably a `VIEW` instead with [`CREATE VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html):

```
 CREATE VIEW client_sales AS
   SELECT Client, count(*) AS Sales FROM sale_tbl GROUP BY Client
```

The advantage of a view is it's always up to date. If you're having performance problems you could look into materialized views that can help address that.